# How to show an ionic-icon (fa icon) with ng-click function?

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework, icons

I need to show an ionic-icon only when the button is clicked.

I tried to put a class on that icon an did it:

```
 .icn { visibility: visible; }
```

But it didn't work, does someone know another way?

Comment: you are going to have to provide more code if you want to get an appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<button ng-init="showIcon=false" ng-click="showIcon=!showIcon">Show icon</button>
<span class="ion-pizza" ng-show="showIcon"> Pizza</span>
```

We initialize the variable `showIcon` to `false`, then toggle its value to the opposite (either `true` or `false`) every time the button is clicked. The icon element is only shown when `showIcon` is `true`.